# LED TV connected to CCTV DVR through HDMI cable is causing a problem

Tags: wiring

I have connected an LED TV to my CCTV DVR through an HDMI cable and the picture quality is very good, but it is causing a problem. Whenever any electric switch is turned on or off, the picture goes for few seconds and then comes back again.

After a few days the HDMI port is fried and also the DVR is burnt. I changed the HDMI cable and put in a new DVR; the same happened: after a few days the DVR is burnt again, and this time the TFT connected to the VGA port has also gone (the card burnt).

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem or how it could be fixed?

Comment: Where in the world are you, and does this TV require a grounded (3 prong/contact) outlet to function?

Comment: @Anil - I've proposed some changes to your question to remove the All Caps title and make the grammar slightly better. If I've changed the meaning at all, do feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Something is seriously mis-wired.

There are so many things it could be that there is no way to determine that from here.

You should call an experienced electrician to check out the wiring in your house before something catches fire and someone gets hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to immediately return that TV as defective and get another, unless you can prove that the damage us being done by voltage coming in frome somewhere else.

This is not in any way a normal failure pattern; actually diagnosing what's going on would require attacking your setup with test equipment.

Comment: sir I have Changed the LED TV also but the problem is same . problem is due to tube light switches , FAN and motor only . when these switches are switched on or off this is happening. really very disturbed .

Comment: Get an electrician to check your wiring. One of the outlets may be putting voltage onto ground or neutral that it shouldn't.

Comment: Check other plugs in your home and see what the voltages are, they should all be within about 5V of each other. If you have anything much greater then that you have a bad neutral and run do not walk and get a professional.